# chef recipe - module methods not available within resources

Tags: chef-infra

I extended the recipe class via a module to provide some properties which give me global access to my paths, which are dynamically constructed.
Example:

```
module Variables
  def user
    "user_name"
  end
  def user_home
    "/home/#{node['user']}"
  end
end

class Chef::Recipe
  include Variables
end
```

The problem is, that within the resource blocks these methods are not available.

```
bash "do_something_with_property" do
  user user
  code "somecommand #{user_home}"
end
```

NoMethodError: undefined method `user_home' for Chef::Resource::Bash

The odd behavior is, that the user property works fine, but the a property used within the code block does not work.

After this I also included the module into all Resources by doing this:

```
class Chef::Resource
  include Variables
end
```

Now my user_home property behaves differently within resource blocks than when used "outside", meaning:

```
directory "#{user_home}/new_dir" do
  action :create
end
```

creates /home/user_name/new_dir

```
bash "create_dir" do
   code "mkdir #{user_home}/new_dir"
end
```

results in /home//new_dir

I have tested this with a little test-script and everything works fine.

```
module MyModule
def module_method
    puts "blablalba"
end
end

class A
def block_method (&block)
    block.call
end
end

class B
include MyModule

def doit
    a = A.new
    a.block_method { module_method }
end
end

B.new.doit
```

So to me it seems this must be a Chef-specific problem.

Can anyone explain me, why this is happening?

Is there a better solution for a global access to my paths and attributes which get build dynamically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have had success injecting methods into the scope of a resource as follows:

`libraries/helper.rb`:

```
module MyCookbook
  module Helper
    def my_method
      "foobar"
    end
  end
end

Chef::Resource.send(:include, MyCookbook::Helper)
```

`recipes/default.rb`:

```
file 'foo' do
  content my_method
end
```

The key here is `Chef::Resource.send(:include, ...)` which injects your module directly into the `Chef::Resource` class, making your module methods available for all of your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Could you put your paths in as attributes?

Either at an environmental level or a node level?

We do something similar with cookbook attributes were we do this to build the install instructions. In this case we build the install instructions from a databag

```
default['splunk']['server'] = Chef::DataBagItem.load('Splunk', 'Install')["Server"]
default['splunk']['install_args'] = Chef::DataBagItem.load('Splunk', 'Install')["Arguments"]

default['splunk']['installcommands'] = "RECEIVING_INDEXER=\"#{default['splunk']['server']}\" #{default['splunk']['install_args']} /quiet"
```

With all that said I do think the extension of the resources class should have seen you fine. When you say behaved differently inside resources as opposed to outside. Directory is a resource as well so in that case it's behaving differently between two resources

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Directory

So perhaps it's an issue with one of the resources that's causing the inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: the problem with attributes is that they do not consider overridden values in the role or environment: <br/>  
default['user']    = 'user_name'  
default['user_home']    = "/home#{node['user']}"  
  
thats why I build my user_home path in the recipe (or whereever I need it)

Comment: the inconsistent behavior is caused because for some reason, some properties are evaluated within the block context (like the code attribute on bash) and others (like user and group) are evaluated within the recipe context, where I defined the properties. Anyway, I should not include the same module within the Resource class, because in its context the node is not available and returns different values.

Comment: Could you use a recipe to set the attribute at a node level
node['user_home'] = "/home#{node['user']}" and then it would be playing into the precedence model laid out by opscode. That recipe could be added to the start of the role? Meaning all recipes could then just leverage that attribute and it can be passed into resources?

Maybe that's a little funky for what you're looking to do

Or use environment variables?